# A reopen queue review audit shouldn't show me a question that has an active bounty

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, review-audits

While processing the reopen queue on Super User I was presented with this:

https://superuser.com/review/reopen/88150

I was immediately suspicious as a) the question was quite detailed and b) the only revision appeared to be the addition of an extra image.

When I got to the bottom of the question I saw this:

[image]

Now as a question with an open bounty can't be closed and a bounty can't be added to a closed question this is clearly an audit so all I had to do was click the "reopen" button.

I checked the actual question first just to make sure.

So one of two things needs to happen here.

1. Don't pick questions with an active bounty to use as review audit questions.
2. Don't display the bounty notice if you are using it as a review audit question.

Comment: Granted, I guess most robo-reviewers wouldn't even *think* about the logic behind that—if in the first place they knew that questions with bounties can't be closed.

Comment: Since you saw that on Super User site shouldn't you post this on [SuperUser's meta](http://meta.superuser.com/)? Or are you assuming the issue is "stackexchange" wide?

Comment: @Mike - I'm assuming that the issue is network wide. I see no reason for Super User to have special code in this regard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with the next build, we won't be picking questions with bounties as possible reopen queue audits.

Comment: I just saw a new [Reopen Review with a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2131180).

Comment: I just saw [another one](http://serverfault.com/review/reopen/73513).

Comment: I would like to notify the SO team that this bug is apparently back: [another Reopen review with a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2609908).

Comment: [Still there](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2971976) and [still shown as closed with an active bounty](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmJsO.png).

Comment: [This also happens in the close queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207251/close-review-queue-shouldnt-use-bountied-questions-as-audits).

Comment: I just found another one http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/3625111