# Bounty notice visible in re-open audit

Tags: bug, review, review-audits, vote-to-reopen

If a post with a bounty is used as an audit in the re-open review queue the bounty notice is visible. As you can't close a question with an open bounty this is obviously an audit (allowing me to cunningly circumvent your evil plans).

ChrisF [raised this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169486/a-reopen-queue-review-audit-shouldnt-show-me-a-question-that-has-an-active-boun) on the 28<sup>th</sup> February and it is tagged as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

This is [the review link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/1841326), bounty notice still clearly visible; below is the pre- audit-success screenshot.

> [image: audit fail]

Here's a [second example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/1869135).

<sub>P.S. sorry about the atrocious production values.</sub>

Comment: But that still mean you looked at the post to see it! You "passed the audit" by looking at the post, and thus the audit goal was achieved! Even though I do agree it makes it kind of easy

Comment: I know a couple of people have started using that argument @Hugo. I don't really agree with it... In any case; it's still a bug. You shouldn't have proof that the question is open when doing a re-open audit.

Comment: I skip clicking the link. If number of votes > 2; it normally is an audit ~_~

Comment: It's kind of the same thing with low quality when they say "because of its length" and the post looks like that http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1870081