# Close review queue shouldn't use bountied questions as audits

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, review-audits

I had [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3349943) in the close review queue. It clearly shows the question with a bounty, but bountied questions cannot be closed. Either bounty questions shouldn't be used as audits, or don't display the bounty notice.

[image]

This is the same problem [as indicated here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169486/a-reopen-queue-review-audit-shouldnt-show-me-a-question-that-has-an-active-boun), except it's happening in the close queue rather than reopen.

Comment: Did the presence of the bounty cause you to fail the audit? (although in my opinion it's not a great question and so not a great audit)

Comment: @Richard Sort of, yes. I saw the bounty, then, knowing that bounty questions can't be closed, I clicked close to see what would happen. I had not considered the possibility of an audit.

Comment: Ah, a fair point, curiosity and cats and all that. Really the audit shouldn't be failed until you actually click a final close reason

Comment: Related: [Bounty notice visible in re-open audit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174825/bounty-notice-visible-in-re-open-audit).

Comment: In some respects, if you see a bounty, you should know it is an audit (and it should be a free sign that you were paying attention).  As long as the passing action is always "Leave Open", it should be ok.

Comment: I think the real solution here is to replace the bounty notice with one that reads, "THIS IS AN AUDIT, IF YOU VOTE TO CLOSE YOU WILL FAIL" and then see how many people *still* click "close" out of curiosity...

Comment: @psubsee2003 That's true, if the reviewer knows that bounty questions can't be closed. I did, and probably would have figured out it was an audit if I'd thought about it, but there's no good reason to think the average reviewer would know this. Most users don't read the FAQs. Bounties are rare, and how often does one attempt or even think about closing one? This was the first time I ever did.

Comment: ... and probably the last time, right?

Comment: Isn't it possible that a bounty question could be in the CV queue without being an audit? If it made it to the queue before the bounty was offered, would the act of offering a bounty remove it? Moreover, I've seen plenty of bountied questions that **should** be closed. The only reason they stay open is because of an active bounty, and if I saw one of them in the queue, it wouldn't feel *right* to click "Leave Open", because it doesn't deserve it. I'd have to skip.

Comment: @Geobits When a question gets bountied, existing close votes stay, but expire during the bounty period. New votes cannot be added during the bounty. If you see a bountied question that should be closed, flag for diamond attention and explain the situation in the "other" box. This is currently the only way to deal with such questions. Judging by the previous comments, normally bountied questions are not shown in the close queue. Related reading: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14591/191706
http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120675/191706

Comment: @EsotericScreenName That was my main question, I guess. psubsee's comment implies that you should *know* it's an audit if it's in the queue, but I don't know if that's a fact, or just an assumption.