# Don't display obvious clues from known good audit reviews

Tags: feature-request, bounties, review-audits

So there's a question in the close review queue.  Its 0 score and looks to be ok at the top, but its long and I'm scrolling down to see if there's a multi-part question or something else that is too broad being asked as I get to the bottom.

And then **BLAM** in big red text, it is obvious this is an audit.  There's a bounty on the question.

[image: Bountied audit review]

<sub>Yes, this is a screen shot after the review, but it was there in the audit too.</sub>

You can't place a close vote on a bountied question and so there's no way for this to be in the queue any other way than an audit.  Looks good without actually reading the actual text of the question and I pass the audit.

**The feature request**:  Don't show bounties on known good questions when using them as audits.

<sub>Yes, I believe a good audit system requires you to read the text rather than going off of other hints about the question.</sub>

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207251/close-review-queue-shouldnt-use-bountied-questions-as-audits

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy ahh, thank you.  Yep.  Thats the dup.

Comment: Congratulations. You passed.

Comment: Another possible dupe target: [Bounty notice visible in re-open audit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174825/bounty-notice-visible-in-re-open-audit) or [A reopen queue review audit shouldn't show me a question that has an active bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169486/a-reopen-queue-review-audit-shouldnt-show-me-a-question-that-has-an-active-boun)

Comment: **STOP. Look and Listen.** This was an audit, designed to see who would whinge about it being too easy or getting banned from reviewing. **You didn't pass.**

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Aspects of the review queue that make it possible to get a pass *without* actually reading the question though are counter productive.  Ideally, one should have to *always* read the full and complete question to make *any* decision - audit or otherwise.

Comment: @MichaelT: I understand, it was only meant to be in jest :)