# Review audit for low quality posts choose an answer with bounty

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

When reviewing Low Quality Posts queue I got an answer which received 50 rep bounty. It wasn't hard to pass this review audit.
I don't know if choosing awarded answers for audits is appropriate, but at least don't show the bounty in the review.

Comment: The people who are the targets of the audits wouldn't notice the bounty.  The fact that you noticed it means you passed.

Comment: Maybe, but in reopen queue it was considered a bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170321/133648

Comment: But then again, bounties can be awarded to bad answers.

Comment: That was a legit bug because it is physically impossible for a closed post to have an active bounty, so it will never appear in the reopen question.  Your issue here is not a bug, because it is possible for low quality posts to receive a bounty (although it would be rare).  This is a feature request to change the default behavior